# Link Harvester - How can i harvest YouTube Video ID using Perl?

Tags: perl

Okay here is what i am trying to do

```
use lwp;
my $ua ="mozzila";
my $search = ua->get("http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=funny+video&aq=f")->content;

while ($search =~m,# ok i do not know what i must put here,sgi)
{
print "$1/n";
}
```

That's all. Can someone can helped me..

Comment: `LWP` must be in upper case. `Mozilla` is capitalised, spelled with one `z` and two `l`. Newline is written with a backslash, thus: `\n`. - Programming teaches you to pay attention to details.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($search =~ m/href="\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)"/) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

Comment: You forgot the dashes and underscores.

Answer (score 0):

```
use LWP::Simple;
print $_."\n" for (get("http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=funny+video&aq=f") =~ m/href="\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)"/g);
```